How to update a SQL column in a stored procedure if the column was added?
I have a stored procedure where I select records from a table and I added a column for a flag (ReviewedFlag).
If I need to update this field how can I do it outside of the stored procedure? I need to do this so I can pick up records in future query where the records are flagged as 1 under the ReviewedFlag.
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spHRLaserficheRetirementsResignationsImport]
    @EmployeeID VARCHAR(MAX) = '0',
    @Flag VARCHAR(MAX) = 'PF'
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @PackageCmd varchar(2000)
    DECLARE @FileName   varchar(255)
    DECLARE @TodayDate  varchar(2000)
    DECLARE @script     varchar(255)

    SELECT @TodayDate =  CONVERT(varchar(12), GETDATE(), 110) + '_' + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(12), GETDATE(), 108), ':', '')

    PRINT @TodayDate

    IF @FLAG = 'PF'
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            -- rr.*
            0 AS ReviewedFlag,
            rr.EmployeeID AS EmployeeID,
            rr.SubmissionType AS SubmissionType,
            rr.TransID, rr.InstanceID AS InstanceID, 

When I execute the stored procedure I get all of the records and a new column ReviewedFlag is added; however how can I update the flag for an individual record.
The update would change the flag from 0 to 1 that way we know it was reviewed on the backend.

Do the results of this SELECT statement get written to a table or are they just dumped out as a result set output of this procedure? If the latter, then it would make sense to write the results to a table as part of your procedure. Then you can SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE all you want.

The results are just dumped as a result set output of the procedure. I do not have the ability to change the table we are sourcing the information from.

There is no need to change the table you are sourcing from, but it sounds like the creation of a new table to hold these results would be appropriate. Do you have access rights to create a table and dump these results into them so you can continue working them with whatever workflow you have that flips this value to a 1?

What if all the records are 0 to begin with how can they be updated?

Yes, I do have these access rights and I think that is what 'PksToFlagAsReviewed' table is meant to be as the user below has guided.

Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

You could add a parameter to the stored procedure to identify the records you want to have 1 for the ReviewedFlag. Maybe a ReviewedCriteria varchar. Then use that criteria to query for the PKs to return with 1 via CASE when creating the results.
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spHRLaserficheRetirementsResignationsImport]

--DECLARE
     @EmployeeID VARCHAR(MAX) = '0'
    ,@Flag VARCHAR(MAX) = 'PF'
    ,@ReviewedCriteria VARCHAR(MAX)=''
    --,@ReviewFlag  VARCHAR(MAX) = '0'

...
    @SQL= "SELECT pkItemToFlag  INTO #PksToFlagAsReviewed FROM ...
    WHERE" + @ReviewedCriteria 
    EXEC @SQL

...
SELECT 
       --rr.*
      CASE WHEN pk in (SELECT pkItemToFlag FROM PksToFlagAsReviewed ) THEN
1 as ReviewedFlag
ELSE 0 END as ReviewedFlag,**
       rr.EmployeeID as EmployeeID,
       rr.SubmissionType as SubmissionType,
     rr.TransID, rr.InstanceID as InstanceID,  


This helps! However, if ReviewedFlag is not a column on the table how can I update this column outside of the stored procedure?

Dump the results of the stored procedure into a temp table to gain the ability to update any of the columns.
